# EPiServer XForm editor reverts default value on radio buttons on save

Tags: xforms, episerver-7

When editing a EPiServer XForm (in the CMS) it seems that the XForm editor does not save the default settings state when working with radio buttons.

What I do:
I begin editiong a XForm and, in the XForm editor preview window, I select a radio button collection with has two options ("Private" And "Corporate") with "Private" checked as default.
I uncheck "Private" as default (since neither of the two options are to be pre-selected) and press "Save" to save the radio button collection field. The XForm preview updates correctly and shows that no radio button is checked.

But when I try to save the entire form and the XForm preview is reloaded, the radio button collection I just edited reverts back and "Private" is again pre-checked!

Any idea why this happens?

The form is implemented in a Block container and runs in a EPiServer CMS 7.5 MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser myself; the error occurs if the value-fields in the radion button collection is left blank.

So make sure your value-fields has some kind of value entered, when appropiate.